# How To Get HTML Eelement From Another Page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a site that provides Windows software that users can download. I want to retrieve text on another page.

**Software Review Page (e.g: domain.com/obs-studio/):**

```
<ul class="software_facts">
    <li>
        <div class="dorat">
            <div class="labelimg">[thumbnail]</div> 
            <div class="wp-block-button is-style-squared">
                <form name="myform1" action="/download-page/" method="post"><input name="bode" type="hidden" value="https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases/download/25.0.8/OBS-Studio-25.0.8-Full-Installer-x64.exe"></form>
                <div class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" onclick="document.myform1.submit()">Download (24 MB)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bg">
        <p class="labelnil">Nilai:</p>
        [kkratings]
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="label">Version:</p>
        <p itemprop="softwareVersion">25.0.8</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bg">
        <p class="label">Publisher:</p>
        <p itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Jim</span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="label">Sistem Operasi:</p>
        <p itemprop="operatingSystem">Windows</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bg">
        <p class="label">Kategori Aplikasi:</p>
        <p itemprop="applicationCategory">Multimedia</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="label">Licence:</p>
        <p>Freeware</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The user is directed to the domain.com/download-page/ page when clicking on the "Download (24MB)" button.

**Download Page (e.g. domain.com/download-page/):**

```
<p>OBS Studio was developed by <strong>Jim</strong>, the latest version is <strong>25.0.8</strong>.</p>
```

I want the "**Jim**" and "**25.0.8**" sections to change according to the software information that the user wants to download on the previous page.

I use Wordpress, how do I do this with Javascript or PHP. Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you own both of these pages why not retrieve form the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

**In Software Review Page**

Use the input tag with hidden type to have publisher and software version values to send in the post method.

```
<ul class="software_facts">
<li>
    <div class="dorat">
        <div class="labelimg">[thumbnail]</div> 
        <div class="wp-block-button is-style-squared">
            <form name="myform1" action="/download-page/" method="post"><input name="bode" type="hidden" value="https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases/download/25.0.8/OBS-Studio-25.0.8-Full-Installer-x64.exe">

                <input name="publisher" type="hidden" value="Jim">
                <input name="softwareVersion" type="hidden" value="25.0.8">

            </form>
            <div class="wp-block-button__link has-background has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color" onclick="document.myform1.submit()">Download (24 MB)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="bg">
    <p class="labelnil">Nilai:</p>
    [kkratings]
</li>
<li>
    <p class="label">Version:</p>
    <p itemprop="softwareVersion">25.0.8</p>
</li>
<li class="bg">
    <p class="label">Publisher:</p>
    <p itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Jim</span></p>
</li>
<li>
    <p class="label">Sistem Operasi:</p>
    <p itemprop="operatingSystem">Windows</p>
</li>
<li class="bg">
    <p class="label">Kategori Aplikasi:</p>
    <p itemprop="applicationCategory">Multimedia</p>
</li>
<li>
    <p class="label">Licence:</p>
    <p>Freeware</p>
</li>
```

**In Download Page**

```
<p>OBS Studio was developed by <strong><?php echo $_POST['publisher']; ?></strong>, the latest version is <strong><?php echo $_POST['softwareVersion']; ?></strong>.</p>
```

Please note that I have sent the values in the superglobal variable called `$_POST` with the keys provided. Use echo statements to print the values from these variables.

Comment: Unfortunately I made a software information table manually. If I use this method, I have to edit thousands of posts. Is there another way?

Comment: @RenomuReza Is it available in Database ?

Answer (score 0):

you need create a crone job to update the software information table data by `file_get_html` the web page you want to grab the data from . Using `file_get_html` , the output will be an String, so create a `DOM` using it and extract your desired content from the `DOM` content and save to your database table

refer : [reference to html dom paser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577654/7468159)